# Embedded VF page's refresh issue

Tags: visualforce, javascript, commandbutton

This is an Embedded VF page on the standard Contact detail page. I am having a Command button on my VF page with following JS function:

```
<apex:commandButton value="Click ME" onclick="jsFunction(); return false;"/>
...
function jsFunction(){
   if(confirm('Do you want to continue?')){ 
        processing(); 
    }else{
        pageReload();    
  }
}
function processing(){
    <!-- Action functions to update the Contact fields-->
    pageReload();
}
function pageReload(){
    window.top.location.href='/{!Contact.Id}';     
}
```

Page reloads successfully(on two occasions), but I am not seeing the updated value of the Parent Contact record reflecting immediately. I need to refresh the browser window manually to see the new changes. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that's expected. In fact, this probably shouldn't work at all, because you're prematurely cancelling the actionFunction (it's asynchronous). What you end up with is a situation that's a race condition; will the network callout reach the server before the page unloads (which automatically terminates all network activity)?

Instead, make sure you put pageReload in the onComplete for the actionFunction:

```
<apex:actionFunction name="updateContact" action="{!...}" oncomplete="pageReload()" />
```

Comment: Thing is, I am having a Status (Processing..) in the actionFunction, I wanted to reload the page before the Processing timer(5000ms) ends. That way end users will not get to see process completion and page loads in between.

Comment: @ArnoldJr. At any point before the call returns, the new data hasn't been committed to the database, so reloading won't show the new data. You need to wait until the transaction completes, and no sooner. Using oncomplete is the ideal situation, but you might also be able to use `onbeforedomupdate` instead; that's the absolutely earliest point in time that you can guarantee the data is committed.

Comment: I see. I think I would go with  the `onbeforedomupdate`, as I can see from the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionFunction.htm) too. Great, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Congratulations @sfdcfox for reaching 200k officially.